# How to get all locals in Express view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to figure out a way to get access to all the app.locals in the views.  In my app.js I have

```
app.locals.title = "Title"
app.locals.page = "Page 1"
```

This is good, and in the views, I can access each with

```
<%= title %>
<%= page %>
```

However, is there a way (without doing something like `app.locals.xyz.title`) to get all the `locals` in the view so I can do something like this:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < locals.length; i ++ ){ %>
    <li><%= locals[i] %></li>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to explitly pass it:

```
res.locals.locals = res.locals;
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= locals %>
```